# Angular 2/4 Typescript Array contents not updating

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm having a problem with updating the contents of an array in an Angular component.

The array with name `arr` is created to store the values that is used by the dataset for the `ChartJS` chart.

On `ngOnInit`, I run `retrieveTempDataReturn()` function which returns `_arr`, an array of retrieved values, from a data service, and I assign the `_arr` array into `arr` array I declared on top.

After the page has loaded, I run `displayArray()` function which displays the contents of the `arr` array, using click event on a button. The output in the browser console is as follows:

```
Array contents: 22.1,22.1,23.1,24.1,25.1,26.1,25.1,24.1,22.1,21.1
```

Thus, I can see that the retrieved data is successfully updated into the `arr` array.

Then, I run another function using click event on a button, `retrieveHumidDataAssign()` which retrieves another set of data from the same data service and assigns the data into the `arr` array right away. Later in the function, I console.log() the contents of the `arr` array and I can see the values updated in the `arr` array. The output in the browser console is as follows:

```
Array assigned Humid: 56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56
```

But then when I the `displayArray()` again to view the content in the `arr` array, the content is still the original content. The output in the browser console is as follows:

```
Array contents: 22.1,22.1,23.1,24.1,25.1,26.1,25.1,24.1,22.1,21.1
```

The content of `arr` array seemed to be changed in the `console.log` part of `retrieveHumidDataAssign()`. But it is somehow not changed when I separately run another function to display its contents.

Why does this happen? And how do I update the content in the array? Please help me.

Below is the component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import {BaseChartDirective} from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'chartjs.component.html'
})
export class ChartJSComponent {

  arr = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.arr = this.retrieveTempDataReturn();
  }

//function that retrieves and returns array of temperature values
  retrieveTempDataReturn(){
    var _arr = new Array();
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(function(response){
      console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
      for(var item of response){
        console.log("Pushing " + item.Temperature);
        _arr.push(item.Temperature);
      }
      console.log("Array returned: " + _arr);
    });
    return _arr;
  }

//function that retrieves and assign array into the "arr" array
  retrieveHumidDataAssign(){
    var _arr = new Array();
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(function(response){
      console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
      for(var item of response){
        _arr.push(item.Humidity);
      }
      this.arr = _arr;
      console.log("Array assigned Humid: " + this.arr);
    });
  }

//display the data on the chart by using "arr" array in the dataset for the chart
  refreshChart(){
    console.log("To display: " + this.arr);
    this.datasets = [{
      label: "Values",
      data: this.arr 
    }];
  }

//function to display the contents of the array
  displayArray(){
    console.log("Array contents: " + this.arr);
  }

//arrays that are used by Chart JS chart for data visualization
  private datasets = [
    {
      label: "Values",
      data: []
    }
  ];

  private labels = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'];

  private options = {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  };

}
```

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: where and how did you called function `displayArray` and `retrieveHumidDataAssign`?

Comment: I call the function via a button on the .html using click event.

Comment: I call the functions via their repective buttons on the .html using click event. For example, 
`          <button (click)="retrieveHumidDataAssign()">Retrieve Humid</button>
          <button (click)="displayArray()">displayArray</button>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have to keep the context while using `this` in `callbacks`, else `this` will turn to **callback function** itself。

you can use `arrow function` here

```
//function that retrieves and assign array into the "arr" array
retrieveHumidDataAssign(){
  var _arr = new Array();
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe(response => {     // <----arrow function here
    ...
    this.arr = _arr;
    console.log("Array assigned Humid: " + this.arr);
  });
}
```

Comment: OMG!!! Thanks a lot! That solves the problem! But what is the difference between function(response) {} and response => {}. I thought they are the same?

Comment: @KelvinWeiMinn `this` will change while using it in callbacks, you can confirm by `console.log(this)` in callback function. While `arrow function` will here you keep your original context while in callbacks.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! You saved my life!